# Using vuelidate with vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I am using vuelidate with vuetify.
I have some v-text-fields using the same error-messages handler.

In the handler function to show the error message, I´d like to get the fieldtext causing the error in order to use only a handler function, instead of create many similares functions.

Is there a  way to do it?

```
<v-text-field
class="purple-input"
label="Data"
type="date"
v-model="preco_proced.data_valor1"
:error-messages="dataValorErrors"
persistent-hint
required
></v-text-field>

<v-text-field
class="purple-input"
label="Data"
type="date"
v-model="preco_proced.data_valor2"
:error-messages="dataValorErrors"
persistent-hint
required
></v-text-field>

//error-messages
dataValorErrors() {
      const errors = [];
      //here I need the correct field:data_valor1, data_valor2 .....  
      if (!this.$v.preco_proced.data_valor??????.$dirty) return errors;
      !this.$v.preco_proced.data_valor???????.required &&
        errors.push("Data é obrigatório");
      return errors;
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can do this.

Let's say we want to validate `firstName` and `email` and the `validations` option is setup like:

```
validations: {
  firstName: { required },
  email: { required, email },
},
```

and in the template we need to update `v-text-field` like:

```
<v-text-field 
  label="First name*" 
  v-model.trim="firstName" 
  required 
  :error-messages="getErrors('firstName', $v.firstName)" 
  @blur="$v.firstName.$touch()">
</v-text-field>

<v-text-field 
  label="Email*" 
  required 
  v-model.trim="email" 
  :error-messages="getErrors('email', $v.email)" 
  @blur="$v.email.$touch()">
</v-text-field>
```

and now we just need to add `getErrors` method for the js code like:

```
methods: {
  validate() {
    this.$v.$touch();
    if (this.$v.$invalid) {
      return;
    }
  },
  getErrors(name, model) {
    const errors = [];
    if (!model.$dirty) return errors;
    switch (name) {
      case "firstName":
        !model.required && errors.push("First name is required.");
        break;
      case "email":
        !model.email && errors.push("Must be valid e-mail");
        !model.required && errors.push("E-mail is required");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return errors;
  }
}
```

You can keep adding multiple switch cases for other text fields also, as needed. I hope this demo example will help.

**DEMO:**

```js
Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default)
const { required, email } = window.validators

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  validations: {
    name: { required },
    email: { required, email },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.$v.$touch();
      if (this.$v.$invalid) {
        return;
      }
    },
    getErrors(name, model) {
      const errors = [];
      if (!model.$dirty) return errors;
      switch (name) {
        case "name":
          !model.required && errors.push("First name is required.");
          break;
        case "email":
          !model.email && errors.push("Must be valid e-mail");
          !model.required && errors.push("E-mail is required");
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      return errors;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuelidate@0.7.5/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuelidate@0.7.5/dist/validators.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <form>
          <v-text-field v-model="name" :error-messages="getErrors('name', $v.name)" :counter="10" label="Name" required @input="$v.name.$touch()" @blur="$v.name.$touch()"></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field v-model="email" :error-messages="getErrors('email', $v.email)" label="E-mail" required @input="$v.email.$touch()" @blur="$v.email.$touch()"></v-text-field>
          <v-btn class="mr-4" @click="validate">submit</v-btn>
        </form>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn´t work. I get an error if I pass parameter to error-messages function. Something as vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.valorErrors is not a function"

found in

---> <ProcedimentoPlanos> at src/components/planos/ProcedimentoPlano.vue
       <VCard>
         <Planos> at src/components/planos/Planos.vue

Comment: The error occurs id I use parameters as : :error-messages="dataValorErrors(someparams)"

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: You don't need to post the full code. Just add one text field and show the error you got.

Comment: I have also added a small demo here to show that it is working fine.

Comment: Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/luizalves/pen/qBbPpaj?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fforms%2F

Comment: Update: https://codepen.io/luizalves/pen/qBbPpaj?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fforms%2F

Comment: The issue is you have declared `nameErrors` function inside the `computed` option, but it needs to be inside the `methods` option. After adding inside `methods` it works fine.

Comment: The vuetify instructions demo at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/  declares it into computed. Is ok  move it to methods?

Comment: Yes, it is ok to move it to methods. They have done it using computed prop because those are individual error for each model. There we do not need to pass params.